# regular expression match everything after the last space with the word of max 2 or 5 characters

Tags: regex

First it need to match the last space of the string

*"this is a test NL"*  with the code `(.*\s)` i get the word `NL`

*"this is a test NL-NL"*  with the code `(.*\s)` i get the word `NL-NL`

But

*"this is a test NL Search"*  with the code `(.*\s)` i get the word `Search`  this is wrong. It should return nothing

The last word my have 2 or 5(with special char `-` or `/`) character. This is de code but it's not working

```
(.*\s)(\w{2}|\w-/{5})
```

Comment: `^.*\s(?=(?:\w{2}|[\w\/-]{5})$)|.+`? Show how you are using the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a capturing group if you want to capture the value (or make it non capturing `(?:`) with a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and an alternation using `|` to match either 2 word chars or match 5 times one of the listed.

```
^.*\s(\w{2}|[\w/-]{5})$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cwaSPw/1)

Note that `\s` could also match a newline.

---

If the `/` and `-` can not occur 2 times after each other, not at the start or end and there must be at least 1 occurrence of them:

```
^.*\s(\w{2}|(?=[\w/-]{5}$)\w+(?:[/-]\w+)+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Plv8IV/1)

---

Or make the second part of the string optional

```
^.*\s([a-zA-Z]{2}(?:[/-][a-zA-Z]{2})?)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zzZTHC/1)

Comment: @ftft32 The pattern does not match that string https://regex101.com/r/uXdsEx/1 How are you using the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like `(?<=\s)(\w{2}|[\/\-\w]{5})$`

Where the different parts means:

- `(?<=\s)` Positive lookbehind should be a space (start match after)
- `(...|...)` Either ... or ...
- `\w{2}` Any two word characters
- `[\/\-\w]{5}` Slash, hyphen or any word character (five times)
- `$` End of line

You can test the expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/ZmeHWf/2).